# Problems with label in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a multiple bar chart with labels, but it doesn´t look good, because the labels are stacked, I put the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yocxuxn9/)

The part of the code that I am using is:

```
state.selectAll("text.state")
                    .data(function(d) {
                        return d.quantities;
                    })
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return x1(d.name) + 2;
                    })
                    .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return y(d.value);
                    })
                    .style("fill", "#000000")
                    .attr("font-size", 10)
                    .attr("font-weight", 700)
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                    });
```

I tried to put the labels in vertical form, I use `.attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)');`

But it looks stacked

I hope that you can help me with this

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yocxuxn9/2/

I just used `transform`, `translate`, `rotate` attribute like you instead of x and y values

```
 state.selectAll("text.state")
                    .data(function(d) {
                        return d.quantities;
                    })
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                      return "translate(" + x1(d.name) + ","+y(d.value)+")rotate(90)"; 
                    })
                    .style("fill", "#000000")
                    .attr("font-size", 10)
                    .attr("font-weight", 700)
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                    });
```

Comment: @FabianSierra Glad I could help!